# show site under maintenance view page for all Error/Exceptions in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, exception, error-handling

I am beginner to laravel. I came across one laravel application. In that I need to handle all types of exceptions/ errors that are getting. Exceptions like ViewExceptions, ErrorExceptions etc. I need to show one view page(site under maintenance) for all those system exceptions, errors and for all database or coding exceptions and errors.

I have checked [Laravel Error handling](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#http-exceptions) and also googled for solutions. But more I searched I am getting confused for solution. As the application is already on production, I can't make changes to each controller to handle the exceptions. I am guessing, I need to make changes in App/Exception/Handler class only but not sure how that will work.

Form search I got that I have to make changes like in Handler class:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.site_down', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Above code not showing if there is ViewException.

I have observed that in .env APP_DEBUG is true and in config/app it's false. Does that affect?

How all exceptions or errors will redirect to site_down page? also please guide me exception and error handling in laravel. I am getting more confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the if statement:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    return response()->view('errors.site_down', [], 503);
}
```

You will also probably want to return 503, if you are trying to claim the site is down for maintenance.

In critique of this approach, I think it is dishonest and transparent to your users to claim the site is in maintenance for your errors, and this will not pay itself off in the long run.

Comment: if I use  `return response()->view('errors.site_down');` instead of `return parent::render($request, $exception);` in my `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`, does that affect to application functionalities? I do not need to show that site_down page to particular error_code like 500,503 etc. I need to use that for all exceptions coming so that visitors will not able to see developer's code.

Comment: Yes, but you will still be returning a response code. And if you are trying to claim it is down for maintenance, 503 is the code for that.

Comment: And I am not enough of an expert to tell you what functionality that may block, my biggest concern would be about error logging.

Comment: if `php artisan down` then it will go 503

Comment: @Kurt Friars sorry, i did not get your first comment. Can I change `return` of Handler.php? Actually I came across ' you might start getting blank page when your application encounters an error, if you do mess up handler.php' this statement so I am little afraid of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a blade page on `resources/views/errors/503.blade.php`

You may publish Laravel's error page templates using the `vendor:publish` Artisan command. Once the templates have been published, you may customize them to your liking :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

This command will create all your custom error page on `resources/views/errors/` directory. You can customize as you want.

See official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

Comment: You can do that also for `401`, `403,` `404`, `419`, `429`,`500`,`503`

Comment: Yes, your solution is much better, handle errors the same way but just render the "same" view.

Answer (score 0):

For custom exceptions first you have to make a custom exception file preferably in the exceptions folder `App\Exceptions\CustomException.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class CustomException extends Exception
{
    //
}
```

Then in your exceptions handler file `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use App\Exceptions\CustomException as CustomException;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        // Thrown when a custom exception occurs.
        if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
            return response()->view('error.page.path', [], 500);
        }

        // Thrown when an exception occurs.
        if ($exception instanceof Exception) {
            response()->view('errors.page.path', [], 500);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Remember to `use App\Exceptions\CustomException;` custom exceptions file where ever you need to throw a custom exception like so:

```
use App\Exceptions\CustomException;

function test(){
    throw new CustomException('This is an error');
}
```